# is it possible to make an animation / render of just the glossy passes?

Tags: rendering

My question is about rendering / animations. Is it possible to make an animation of just the glossy passes, say, without the composite view? Sorry if that sounds a bit simplistic, but I am a noob. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here how to in Cycles:

1. First, enable Glossy passes in Render Layers:

[image]

2. Next open node editor in Compositing mode and click Use nodes

[image]

3. Here is the glossy passes, all of them are important.

[image]

4. To make glossy pass you should combine this 3 passes in specific way.
   Add 2 Color mix nodes (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> Color -> Mix) Change one of them to Add, second to Multiply. Gloss Direct will add to Gloss Indirect, then this sum will multiply by Gloss Color (Connect nodes in this way):

[image]

5. So, in this point you can start to render

Comment: It works perfectly, fantastic answer and description thank you.

Comment: @JuJu Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers